# Having issues with /c cmd echo and app in Program Files...on remote machine

Tags: cmd, command, psexec

I'm trying to disable Traps and it asks for a password... if I provide it with echo it messes up the location... this is what I'm running...

```
psexec \\9020m-77 -i -d -s cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cytool.exe"" protect disable
```

having issues when passing password with echo cmd:

```
psexec \\9020m-77 -i -d -s cmd /c echo  1Nstall55# | ""C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cytool.exe"" protect disable
```

'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I just figured out the answer since I just had the same issue.

```
echo  1Nstall55# |
```

Don't leave a space between the password and the pipe. That's the same as entering that trailing space char into the password